# Windows 2008 Domain Controller - Backup (BDC) to Primary (PDC)

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I have created a new domain controller with my single domain forest.  I have also made it DHCP and DNS ready - all 3 services have synchronised with the existing W2K8 domain controller.

I even migrated the FSMO roles and thought everything was fine.  Indeed all machines on network appear to obtain DHCP and DNS from new server and the AD is working on the new server as my internal website uses it for login authentication.

I have just noticed, via BgInfo - Sys Internals - that the new server is showing as "backup" and the old as "primary" - I thought I had already achieved this.  Have the FSMO roles swapped back - as I have yet to have removed the old server from AD (dcpromo).

Do I need to do anything before I run dcpromo on the old server?

Any thoughts appreciated....

Comment: Answered it myself - missed the PDC and Infrastructure Tabs on the Operations Masters task of Active Directory Users and Computers FSMO role change routine.

Incidently, its okay to move the infrastructure operations master to the Global Catalogue Domain Controller - despite the warning - when a single domain exists in a single forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered it myself - missed the PDC and Infrastructure Tabs on the Operations Masters task of Active Directory Users and Computers FSMO role change routine. Incidently, its okay to move the infrastructure operations master to the Global Catalogue Domain Controller - despite the warning - when a single domain exists in a single forest. – Klaptrap 0 secs ago edit